# Find last row in column B and resize table range

Tags: excel, vba

I have two macro enabled workbooks. One is used to collect data by multiple users (Macro for Tracker) and the other one (Tracker) is a place to store data.

"Macro for Tracker" will open the "Tracker", copy paste values in specific columns, save and close it.

I am trying to resize table range in the Tracker to the last row in column B.

Tracker contains columns with formulas and has only one code for timestamp.

I tried to add a private sub, which will run upon opening. It gives me

> subscript out of range

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long

Lrow1 = Sheets("Main").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("B")
Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table2")

ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)
```

Also I was trying to add lines in "Macro for Tracker" workbook, to resize after it will copy paste, but it gets more complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you appear to be referencing a worksheet called `B`. I can only assume (without seeing your workbook) that you actually meant `Main`..

Try this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ob As ListObject
Dim Lrow1 As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("main")
Lrow1 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Set ob = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
ob.Resize ob.Range.Resize(Lrow1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! I did not see this terrible mistake and was almost close to a nervous breakdown

Comment: Good to hear. Don't forget to mark it as answered if you're happy with it.